# How to: multiple instances of Django shared one global variable?

Tags: django, variables, global

I have a Django website, which running several uwsgi processes behide nginx server.
Now what I try to do is , these several Django instances shared one variable, modify it and display it on view function. How to do this?

```
global_v = [1,2,3]

python manage.py runserver 8000

python manage.py runserver 8001

python manage.py runserver 8002

....
```

Comment: what about to use the same DB ?

Comment: Store the information in a common database or in a common file on disk.

Comment: How about make this a setting variable, and doing `django.conf import settings` and `settings.GLOBAL_V` ?

Comment: @levi ,  George Cummins : Avoid using DB or a file,that is why I try to share a global variable.

Comment: @karthikr , I had try this , put that global variable in settings,  but different Django instance looks using diff namespace, they don't shared one .

Answer (score -1):

If common file or database is not acceptable for some reasons, you could use Memcached (or other caching system?) to:

> ... share cache over multiple servers

From [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached).

**EDIT:** an possibly lighter alternative:

Use shared memory though [Python IPC modules](http://semanchuk.com/philip/PythonIpc/). Please note that you will have to use semaphores for serializing access, and pickle/unpickle data manually, as interfaces is simply a file handle.

Comment: This solution is too heavy? All I looking for is a temporary and shareable list...

Comment: Sure, for single variable, it's obviously too heavy. But I've just remembered such thing as Shared Memory, so please check updated answer for alternative.